# push_back using the move constructor does not call the destructor?

Tags: c++

The following code creates a temporary object A and pushes it into a vector.
The copy constructor is deleted and the move constructor is called during the push_back. I am not sure the design of this code is correct, and surely there is a memory leak.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
  char* ptr; 

public:
  A(const string& str)
  {
    ptr = new char[str.size()];
    copy(str.begin(), str.end(), ptr);
    cout << ptr << " Constructor\n" ;
  }

  A(const A& a) = delete;    // copy constructor
  
  A( A&& a)                
  {
    cout << "Move constructor\n";
    ptr = a.ptr;
    a.ptr = nullptr;
  }

  ~A()
  {
    cout << ptr << " Destructor\n";
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
  }

  void print()
  {
    cout << ptr << endl;
  }
};



int main()
{
  vector<A> v;
  v.reserve(5);

  v.push_back( A("hello")  );
  v[0].print();
  cout << "here" << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
    hello Constructor
    Move constructor
```

Why the print function doesn't print, and the destructor is not called? Thanks

Comment: The destructor probably crashes because you try to print nullptr

Comment: I think the problem can be reduced to `std::cout << (char*)nullptr;` - I'm not sure how that printing should behave.

Comment: `std::cout << (char *)nullptr` will call `operator<<()`  that accepts two arguments (the first a specialisation of the templated `std::basic_ostream` by reference, and the second a `const char *`).  That operator assumes the second argument points at (the first character of) a nul-terminated string, and has undefined behaviour otherwise.   Since `(char *)nullptr`  does not point at a nul-terminated string, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: please, add the includes as well next time, so people will be able to copy and paste your code and immediately run it without any modification

Comment: I think your `char*` is missing a null terminator; `std::string::size()` excludes its null terminator.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `ptr = nullptr;` in the destructor doesn't accomplish anything. The object is going away; `ptr` won't exist after the destructor returns, so its value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, your problem lies here:

```
~A()
{
  cout << ptr << " Destructor\n";
  delete[] ptr;
  ptr = nullptr;
}
```

By the time you reach the destructor the object has already been moved from and `ptr == nullptr`. The `char*` overload of `<<` expects a null-terminated string. If `ptr` does not point to a null-terminated string you invoke undefined behavior.

You get the expected output if you change it to

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << " Destructor\n";
```

Because the overload for `void*` just prints the value of the pointer.

[Working Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qMWed)

Comment: I would do an if with void and char branches myself

Comment: @Yakk `if (ptr) std::cout << ptr;` ? Fixes the problem with the `nullptr` but could still fail if `ptr` isnt pointing to a c-string. Not sure, I think its better to stay on the safe side.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has undefined behavior on account of you essentially doing

```
std::cout << (char*)nullptr;
```

Recall that your *moved-from* object has its pointer set to `nullptr`.

That's a precondition violation of those standard library inserters:

> **[ostream.inserters.character]**
>
> ```
> template<class charT, class traits>
>   basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& out, const charT* s);
> template<class charT, class traits>
>   basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& out, const char* s);
> template<class traits>
>   basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, traits>& out, const char* s);
> template<class traits>
>   basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, traits>& out, const signed char* s);
> template<class traits>
>   basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, traits>& out,
>                                           const unsigned char* s);
> ```
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/output.streams#ostream.inserters.character-3) *Preconditions*: `s` is not a null pointer.

Add a null check, or just don't print the pointer value in the destructor.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 -  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . I swung the pendulum back on your answer. Printing `void*` is nice.